# Class Not Found Error in a refactor-moved JSF Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, netbeans

I re factor and move JSF managed bean from one package to another package in Netbeans JSF application. Intermittently I get an error stating that the moved bean is not found in the previous location. I clean and build several times. Still the issue persists. I restarted the GlassFish and even the computer. I find in project including the generate sources, but I could not locate any reference to that Bean. I add the current location to the faces-config.xml, still no result.

The Previous Package is com.divudi.bean
New Package is com.divudi.bean.lab

The Error Message is

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : com/divudi/bean/CollectingCentreController
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/divudi/bean/CollectingCentreController
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1107)
    at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Class.java:1242)
    at java.lang.Class.isMemberClass(Class.java:1232)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.isNonStaticInnerClass(Reflections.java:139)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.divudi.bean.CollectingCentreController
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    ... 41 more
```

The Bean is (Before Adding to faces-config.xml, where annotation is used)

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.divudi.bean.lab;

import com.divudi.bean.SessionController;
import com.divudi.bean.UtilityController;
import com.divudi.data.InstitutionType;
import com.divudi.entity.Institution;
import com.divudi.facade.InstitutionFacade;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author www.divudi.com
 */
@ManagedBean
public class CollectingCentreController {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CollectingCentreController
     */
    public CollectingCentreController() {
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{sessionController}")
    SessionController sessionController;
    @EJB
    private InstitutionFacade ejbFacade;
    List<Institution> selectedItems;
    private Institution current;
    private List<Institution> items = null;
    String selectText = "";

    public List<Institution> getSelectedItems() {
        selectedItems = getFacade().findBySQL("select c from Institution c where c.retired=false and i.institutionType = com.divudi.data.InstitutionType.CollectingCentre  and upper(c.name) like '%" + getSelectText().toUpperCase() + "%' order by c.name");
        return selectedItems;
    }

    public void prepareAdd() {
        current = new Institution();
        current.setInstitutionType(InstitutionType.CollectingCentre);
    }

    public void setSelectedItems(List<Institution> selectedItems) {
        this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
    }

    public String getSelectText() {
        return selectText;
    }

    private void recreateModel() {
        items = null;
    }

    public void saveSelected() {

        if (getCurrent().getId() != null && getCurrent().getId() > 0) {
            getFacade().edit(current);
            UtilityController.addSuccessMessage("savedOldSuccessfully");
        } else {
            current.setCreatedAt(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")).getTime());
            current.setCreater(sessionController.getLoggedUser());
            getFacade().create(current);
            UtilityController.addSuccessMessage("savedNewSuccessfully");
        }
        recreateModel();
        getItems();
    }

    public void setSelectText(String selectText) {
        this.selectText = selectText;
    }

    public InstitutionFacade getEjbFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public void setEjbFacade(InstitutionFacade ejbFacade) {
        this.ejbFacade = ejbFacade;
    }

    public SessionController getSessionController() {
        return sessionController;
    }

    public void setSessionController(SessionController sessionController) {
        this.sessionController = sessionController;
    }

    public Institution getCurrent() {
        if (current == null) {
            current = new Institution();
            current.setInstitutionType(InstitutionType.CollectingCentre);
        }
        return current;
    }

    public void setCurrent(Institution current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    public void delete() {

        if (current != null) {
            current.setRetired(true);
            current.setRetiredAt(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")).getTime());
            current.setRetirer(sessionController.getLoggedUser());
            getFacade().edit(current);
            UtilityController.addSuccessMessage("DeleteSuccessfull");
        } else {
            UtilityController.addSuccessMessage("NothingToDelete");
        }
        recreateModel();
        getItems();
        current = null;
        getCurrent();
    }

    private InstitutionFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public List<Institution> getItems() {
        // items = getFacade().findAll("name", true);
        String sql = "SELECT i FROM Institution i where i.retired=false and i.institutionType = com.divudi.data.InstitutionType.CollectingCentre order by i.name";
        items = getEjbFacade().findBySQL(sql);
        if (items == null) {
            items = new ArrayList<Institution>();
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a configuration of this bean in an xml file (probably the faces-config.xml). Make sure all these configurations are updated as well.

Comment: I have used annotations and did not configure faces-config.xml file initially. Later I add the bean to faces-config.xml file. As there was no solution, I moved the bean back to the old package and after clean and build, it indicated the same issue with other moved beans. So I moved all the beans back to their initial packages and now working without that error. But because of the the hierarchy of beans is not optimally arrange. Thank you for your comment.